# How to implement triplet loss in my project?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, speech-recognition, loss-function

Im doing a project on speaker recognition and I have data set of audio files which from them I take feature of sound ( array of 1x13 ) as input and as output I pick a random integer for each speaker ( let’s say speaker 1 - output = 1 speaker 2 output = 2...)

I was offered to use triplet loss in order to achieve better accuracy but I don’t understand how we implement it in tensor-flow ( there is no examples at all )

From what I understood until now, I take 2 positive and one negative values for each speaker ( for example 2 features of 2 audios files of the same speaker, and one feature of synthetic audio file of another speaker which I will create with wavenet)

But what I do with this features in order to achieve the triplet loss, meaning how I really implement it using tensor flow

Answer (score 0):

The Triplet loss function working is explained in below steps.

**Training Data:**
Like you said, you need to have triplet for each training sample, `Anchor,Positive,Negetive`.

**Architecture of the model:**

The idea is to have 3 identical networks having the same neural net architecture and they should share weights.

[image]

**Model Learning:**

The model not only learned to formulate clusters for different classes at the same time, but it’s also successful in projecting similar-looking data into their neighborhood region. In the case of classification architecture, the model tries to learn a decision boundary between a pair of classes, but the model doesn’t take care of the integrity between similar and dissimilar data within a class.

You can follow this [link](https://github.com/sanku-lib/image_triplet_loss) and this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/v0.9.1/tensorflow_addons/losses/triplet.py) which has the implementation for the triplet loss on TensorFlow, you can follow the same architecture for your data with some changes in it.

Hope this helps you, Happy Learning!